# Pass object outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I'm new to AngularJs. Currently I'm trying to implement a table filtering and then when I click on the delete button it should delete the right object.

this is how I did it before filtering :

```
$scope.rowIndex = -1;
$scope.selectRow = function(index) {
if (index == $scope.rowIndex)
  $scope.rowIndex = -1;
else
  $scope.rowIndex = index;
}
});
```

In my html :

```
ng-repeat="session in sessons " ng-class="{'bg-primary':rowIndex == $index }" ng-click="selectRow($index)"
```

Now after implementing filtering I found out that $index is wrong... So I had to find another way.. I read some articles and all said the same... I just could pass the whole object to the function... But every example did it inside the `ng-repeat`. Unfortunately... I can't do that since I've a external div for the Modal.

So how do I pass the current selected session / row of the table to the function which is in the modal? {{ deleteSession(session) }}

```
<div id="deleteSessionModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Session</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you want to delete these Records?</p>
          <p class="text-warning">
            <small>This action cannot be undone.</small>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteSession(session)">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[this is how my html / table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiTBM.png)

Comment: could you share the sessons  data ?

Comment: check above, updated question

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the session as the value to select row function like that:

```
ng-repeat="session in sessons " ng-class="{'bg-primary':rowIndex == $index }" ng-click="selectRow(session)"
```

and in the function selectRow, you can take the Id from the session and delete it from the sessions list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `$index` to `selectRow` function, send  `session.speakerId` or another specific unique key of sessions:

```
ng-click="selectRow(session.speakerId)"
```

In your controller set/unset selected session:

```
$scope.selectedSessionSpeakerId = null;

$scope.selectRow = function(sess) {
  if (sess == $scope.selectedSessionSpeakerId)
    $scope.selectedSessionSpeakerId = null;
  else
    $scope.selectedSessionSpeakerId = sess;
}
```

And your `deleteSession` function does not receive any arguments. It just check the selected Session unique key and delete that from array:

```
$scope.deleteSession = function() {
  if($scope.selectedSessionSpeakerId) {
    let index = $scope.sessions.findIndex(finction(itm) {
      return itm["speakerId"] == $scope.selectedSessionSpeakerId;
    });
    $scope.sessions.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.selectedSessionSpeakerId = null;
  }
}
```